# Using Python Update the maximum value in each row dataframe with the sum of [column with maximum value] and [column name threshold]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, max

```
Day US  INDIA   JAPAN   GERMANY AUSTRALIA Threshold
11  40  30      20      100     110         5
21  60  70      80      55      57          8
32  12  43      57      87      98          9
41  99  23      45      65      78          12
```

This is the demo data frame,
Here i wanted to choose maximum for each row from 3 countries(INDIA,GERMANY,US) and then add the threshold value to that maximum record and then add that into the max value and update it in the dataframe.
lets take an example :

max[US,INDIA,GERMANY] = max[US,INDIA,GERMANY] + threshold

After performing this dataframe  will get updated as below :

```
Day US  INDIA   JAPAN   GERMANY AUSTRALIA Threshold
11  40  30      20      105     110       5
21  60  78      80      55      57        8
32  12  43      57      96      98        9
41  111 23      45      65      78        12
```

I tried to achieve this using for loop but it is taking too long to execute :

```
df_max = df_final[['US','INDIA','GERMANY']].idxmax(axis=1)
for ind in df_final.index:
    column = df_max[ind]
    df_final[column][ind] = df_final[column][ind] + df_final['Threshold'][ind]
```

Please help me with this. Looking forward for a good solution,Thanks in advance...!!!

Answer (score 0):

First solution compare maximal value per row with all values of filtered columns, then multiple mask by `Threshold` and add to original column:

```
cols = ['US','INDIA','GERMANY']
df_final[cols] += (df_final[cols].eq(df_final[cols].max(axis=1), axis=0)
                        .mul(df_final['Threshold'], axis=0))

print (df_final)
   Day   US  INDIA  JAPAN  GERMANY  AUSTRALIA  Threshold
0   11   40     30     20      105        110          5
1   21   60     78     80       55         57          8
2   32   12     43     57       96         98          9
3   41  111     23     45       65         78         12
```

Or use numpy - get columns names by `idxmax`, compare by array from list `cols`, multiple and add to original columns:

```
cols = ['US','INDIA','GERMANY']

df_final[cols] += ((np.array(cols) == df_final[cols].idxmax(axis=1).to_numpy()[:, None]) * 
                     df_final['Threshold'].to_numpy()[:, None])

print (df_final)
   Day   US  INDIA  JAPAN  GERMANY  AUSTRALIA  Threshold
0   11   40     30     20      105        110          5
1   21   60     78     80       55         57          8
2   32   12     43     57       96         98          9
3   41  111     23     45       65         78         12
```

There is difference of solutions if multiple maximum values per rows.

*First solution add threshold to all maximum, second solution to first maximum.*

```
print (df_final)
   Day  US  INDIA  JAPAN  GERMANY  AUSTRALIA  Threshold
0   11  40    100     20      100        110          5 <-changed data double 100
1   21  60     70     80       55         57          8
2   32  12     43     57       87         98          9
3   41  99     23     45       65         78         12


cols = ['US','INDIA','GERMANY']
df_final[cols] += (df_final[cols].eq(df_final[cols].max(axis=1), axis=0)
                        .mul(df_final['Threshold'], axis=0))

print (df_final)
   Day   US  INDIA  JAPAN  GERMANY  AUSTRALIA  Threshold
0   11   40    105     20      105        110          5
1   21   60     78     80       55         57          8
2   32   12     43     57       96         98          9
3   41  111     23     45       65         78         12
```

---

```
cols = ['US','INDIA','GERMANY']

df_final[cols] += ((np.array(cols) == df_final[cols].idxmax(axis=1).to_numpy()[:, None]) * 
                     df_final['Threshold'].to_numpy()[:, None])

print (df_final)
   Day   US  INDIA  JAPAN  GERMANY  AUSTRALIA  Threshold
0   11   40    105     20      100        110          5
1   21   60     78     80       55         57          8
2   32   12     43     57       96         98          9
3   41  111     23     45       65         78         12
```